# Override ggplot2 legend text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to make a bar chart using ggplot, something very much like:

```
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, fill=gear))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey30", "grey50", "grey70"))
```

Now I would like the first label of the legend (where it says 3 in my example) to say "reference", while keeping the rest of the labels intact, i.e. 4 and 5.

I'm having a very difficult time finding a way to do this. I have not been able to find a question similar to mine somewhere around here.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix factor labels, then plot:

```
# set labes when creating factor
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,
                      levels = c("3", "4", "5"),
                      labels = c("reference", "4", "5"))
```

Or if we want to update label only for `"3"`, after factor conversion:

```
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
levels(mtcars$gear)[levels(mtcars$gear) == "3"] <- "reference"
```

Comment: `labels = c("3" = "reference")` should do as well or not?

Comment: @beetroot Do you mean `factor(mtcars$gear, labels = c("3" = "reference"))`, this doesn't work.

Comment: @beetroot this would only change the legend, to change xaxis as well we will need `scale_x_discrete()`. I would rather fix the data before plotting than messing about in ggplot :)

Comment: yep, ok, from OP's post if appeared that only the legend should be changed, but I agree with you, forgot what I said ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, fill=gear)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +   
scale_fill_manual(
    values=c("grey30", "grey50", "grey70"), 
    labels = c("reference", "4", "5"))
```